# Import certificate with private key programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to use the HttpListener class in a C# application to have a mini webserver serve content over SSL.  In order to do this I need to use the httpcfg tool.  I have a .pfx file with my public and private key pair.  If I import this key pair manually using mmc into the local machine store, everything works fine.  However, if I import this key pair programmatically using the X509Store class, I am not able to connect to my mini webserver.  Note that in both methods the cert is getting imported to the MY store in LocalMachine. Oddly, I am able to view the certificate in mmc once I programmatically import it and when I view it, the UI indicates that a private key is also available for this certificate.

Digging a little deeper, I notice that when I manually import the key pair, I can see a new file appear in `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`, but one does not appear when I import programmatically.  On a related note, when I delete a manually imported certificate, it does not remove the corresponding private key file from the previously mentioned directory.

Ultimately, my question is this: When I programmatically add the certificate to the store, where is the private key being stored and why isn't it accessible to the HttpListener class (HttpApi)?

Note that this question is slightly related but I don't think permissioning is the problem since this is all being done as the same Windows user:
[How to set read permission on the private key file of X.509 certificate from .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425688/how-to-set-read-permission-on-the-private-key-file-of-x-509-certificate-from-ne)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  It had to do with the key storage parameters for the certificate object.  For anyone else that runs into this problem, make sure you construct your `X509Certificate2` objects that you are adding to the store using the `X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet` and `X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet` flags.  This will force the private key to persist in the machine key set location which is required by `HttpApi` (`HttpListener` wraps this).

Comment: Unfortunately I have to wait 48 hours before I can do so at which point I will likely forget to do it.  :(

Comment: I wasted about 30 minutes trying to figure why "X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet & X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet" wasn't working.  Of course, it should be "X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet."  Fairly obvious, just in case someone else tries the same stupid thing that I did.

Comment: There is a small amount of sample code at:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950090

Comment: @Jason you wont believe how much time you saved me. I was already in my 2nd day of research and the whole internet was a giant dead-end. Thank you!

Comment: @json Thanks ( 13 years after)

I was getting this error during https binding using c# code,
`A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070520)`

X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable   made it work !

Answer (score 0):

Is this a 2 way SSL? If it is then did you send over a SSL Certificate Request file generated on your machine? This Certificate Request file will be used to create the SSL and they together form a public private key pair.

Also did you try assigning the cert permission for the user account that is being used to run the web app? You can do this by using the Microsoft WSE 3.0 tool.

Comment: I am just using a self generated key pair for testing at the moment so there is this cert request involved.  I haven't played with anything permissions related yet since all of this is being done as the same user (cert import and running the webserver).  There is no IIS or anything else involved.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer to your question, but here for reference of others going down this path:

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163531.aspx) is a link to a MS chat that gives sample C# code to do what httpcfg does, thus eliminating the need for the tool on deployment.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good link.  I briefly looked into that, but it only goes into how to use the URLACL_SET struct and not the SSL_SET one which is needed for managing the SSL configuration in my scenario.  Unfortunately the SSL_SET struct is quite a bit more complex so it simply became to cumbersome to work with and the httpcfg executable was more convenient.